# Coldfusion: how to extract a substring using regex

Tags: regex, string, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I have a string that has some double quoted substring in it, the " character. In between the double quotes is the data i want.

How can i write a regex to extract "the first data i want" and "the second data i want" from this:

'some string with "the first data i want" and "the second data i want"'

I tried the following code.

```
<cfset mydata = 'some string with "the first data i want" and "the second data i want"'/>

<cfset arrData = ListToArray(mydata ,'"') />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably you could do something trivial like this:

```
<cfset matches = REMatch('"([^"]*)"', mydata) />
<cfdump var="#matches#" label="Example REMatch" />
```

Unfortunately this will also include the double quotes in the Match, and ColdFusion's Regular Expression engine is quite old and shoddy, so it doesn't have support for Lookaheads/Lookbehinds.

The double quotes can be easily replaced, but if you really want to use lookaheads and look-behinds you can resort to using Java's own pattern library.

```
<cfset matches = [] />
<cfset pattern = CreateObject("java","java.util.regex.Pattern").Compile('(?<=")[^"]*(?=")') />
<cfset matcher = pattern.Matcher(mydata) />
<cfloop condition="matcher.Find()">
    <cfset ArrayAppend(matches, matcher.Group()) />
</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#matches#" label="Example of Java Regex" />
```

Comment: IIRC, ColdFusion's RegEx engine can do 'look-behind' but not 'look-ahead'. Or maybe the other way around....it can do one of them.

Comment: CF's regex engine is Apache ORO which can do lookahead but not lookbehind.

Comment: However, you probably don't actually want lookahead/lookbehind in this situation - because they are zero width constructs they don't consume the quotes and thus your second example code will also include ` and ` in the matches array (so it's not much better than ListToArray).

Comment: Just use `"[^"]+"` to match, then [mid](http://cfdocs.org/mid) or `ListFirst(matches[i],'"')` on each one to remove the quotes.

Comment: More info: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1428-ask-ben-extracting-data-with-regular-expressions-vs-coldfusion-list-functions.htm